# How to make ThresholdFilter work in logback

Tags: groovy, logback

I basically followed [the instruction in Chapter 7](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter) of the official logback documentation. Unfortunately, things don't seem to work properly, and I can't figure out why. So, here we are.

What I want to achieve is to log only info and above in console and all debug and above into log files. I have these lines in my `logback.groovy`:

```
appender("CONSOLE", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{YYYY-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    }
    filter(ThresholdFilter) {
        level = INFO
    }
}

logger("vh.FileIO", DEBUG, ['CONSOLE','FILE-DEBUG'])
root(DEBUG, ['CONSOLE'])
```

I thought the `ThresholdFilter` would make `CONSOLE` only take info and above logs. However, I still get debug logs of `vh.FileIO` on the `CONSOLE`. For example, I still get something like this on the console:

```
2013-10-11/21:48:10.537 [main] DEBUG vh.FileIO - Combining all records into file ./output/sip_sample_data_output.csv
```

So, what am I missing here?

### update

After playing with the configuration of logback, I find that the ThresholdFilter works as expected if I use an XML configuration file. However, I still would like to know why it's not working in the groovy configuration file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for the problem is the following: just add import of the class ThresholdProvider at the beginning of "logback.groovy":

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter
```

then it works as expected.

I tried the provided "logback.groovy" on a simple project. There's another problem: messages are written twice to the console. I think this could be fixed by fine-tuning "logger" and "root" calls.